# Align two tikz-cd pictures in itemize environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

In the following example, I want both *A* 's to be aligned. I messed around with the `align` environment, but I had no success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item First diagram:
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        B \rar &A \dar \\
               &C
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\item Second diagram:
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \dar &B \lar\\
        C
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\item The $A$'s are not aligned.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `trim left` and `trim right` as such:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item First diagram:
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[trim left=(a),trim right=(a)]
        B \rar &|[alias=a]|A \dar \\
               &C
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\item Second diagram:
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[trim left=(a),trim right=(a)]
        |[alias=a]|A \dar &B \lar\\
        C
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\item The $A$'s are aligned.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```